# Алгоритм самой быстрой победы в математической игре

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, любой-язык, логика

Один мой друг предложил мне поиграть в игру. Это пошаговая игра и на двух игроков. Вот правила:

- Оба игрока загадывают четырёхзначное число.
- Потом они подбрасывают монетку, чтобы решить, кто ходит первым.
- Первый игрок пытается отгадать число второго игрока.
- Если у него не получается, второй игрок сообщает первому игроку два числа:

  1. Первое число означает количество угаданных цифр в числе без учёта позиции.
  2. Второе число означает количество правильно угаданных позиций.

     Пример: 
     Первый игрок загадал число `2737`
     Второй игрок пытается отгадать  число. Он говорит `2274`
     Первый игрок отвечает ему `2, 1`
- Потом они меняются
- Это продолжается до тех пор, пока один из них не отгадает всё число оппонента.

Я выиграл в этой игре пользуясь следующим алгоритмом:

Представим, что наш оппонент загадал `4856`

1. Сначала мы загадываем 4 случайных цифры.

   `1234`

   Затем смотрим на ответ. В нашем случае это `1, 0`
2. На следующий ход мы повышаем первую цифру на один от самой большой, присутствующей в числе. В нашем случае это 5.

   `5234 #=> [2, 0]`
3. Так как мы обнаружили новую цифру, мы двигаем её вправо на одну позицию, заменяя уже существующую. Также мы снова увеличиваем первую цифру на один.

   `6534 #=> [3, 0]`
4. `7654 #=> [3, 1]` Мы отгадали первую позицию. Это 5 или 6, так как 7 не увеличила наше первое число в ответе.
5. `8654 #=> [4, 1]` Ура! Мы нашли все цифры. Осталось только найти для них правильные места. Так что мы попробуем попереставлять их, начиная с самой левой.
6. `6854 #=> [4, 2]`
7. `5864 #=> [4, 1]` Тут мы потеряли одну цифру. Это значит, что она была на правильном месте. Вернём её и будет игнорировать в будущем.
8. `4856 #=> [4, 4]` Мы выиграли.

---

Мы выиграли за 8 ходов. Я пробовал играть в эту игру с другими людьми, используя этот алгоритм, и в большинстве случаем выигрывал. Но всё же мне кажется, что он слишком примитивен. Должен быль способ выиграть эту игру при любом раскладе за наименьшее количество ходов. Есть идеи?

Comment: Это же "быки и коровы"? для них я когда-то в детстве, когда еще не программировал - вернее, только на калькуляторе - для проверки идеи несколько раз играл так:вариантов не так много, 5040, словом, составлен список. Далее по ответу вычеркиваем все не годящиеся, и составляем такой вопрос, чтобы ответ на него выбрасывал как можно больше вариантов (там я придумывал какие-то эвристики). Выигрывалось очень быстро, но так как тому уже далеко не один десяток лет, детали не помню.

Comment: Какой ответ подразумевается на `4311`, если загадано `1199`? `1,0` или `2,0` или `4,0`?

Comment: @jfs  в таком случае `[2, 0]`

Comment: А для `4321` было бы `1,0`?

Comment: @jfs всё верно.

Comment: @Harry почему 5040 а не 9000?

Comment: @jfs Потому что прокололся :) Считал для **классических** быков-коров, не допускающих повторения цифр. Впрочем, все равно ошибся. Должно быть 9*9*8*7 = 4536 вариантов.

Comment: слово "быстрый" означает наименьшее *среднее* кол-во ходов или наименьшее *максимальное* кол-во ходов в худшем случае? http://slovesnov.users.sourceforge.net/index.php?bullscows,russian

Comment: Провел эксперимент - сколько ходов нужно (см. мой ответ, дополнение).

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to solve the “Mastermind” guessing game?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1185634/4279). В частности [вот несколько алгоритмов в Питоне](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496907/) (например, `s_bestinfo` стратегия использует меньше 6 шагов среднем и 9 в худшем случае—для сравнения @Harry's решение более 6 шагов в среднем и 11 шагов в худшем (один прогон по всем числам)). Оптимальное решение может содержать попытки, которые сами не могут быть решением (чтобы информацию получить), поэтому кол-во кандидатов на каждом шаге не уменьшается (минус уже выбранные).

Comment: @jfs Забавно, что я попробовал применить свой способ, чтобы "химичить" за второго игрока - т.е. в ответ на запрос мы смотрим, что осталось, и выбираем возможный ответ, дающий максимальное количество остающихся допустимыми вариантов - т.е. реально задуманного числа нет, мы с ним тянем до последнего... Для классических быков-коров вышло именно так - от 6 до 9 шагов, ни меньшего, ни большего значения шагов не было в серии из 100000 игр. Интересно бы натравить программы друг на друга...

Comment: @Harry: в "классических быки-коровы" повторения запрещены. У автора mastermind игра с 4 дырками и 10 цветами (плюс/минус `0` на первом месте). Ещё data-point: [Алгоритм Кнута (modified)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7828779/4279) для задачи в вопросе в среднем требует `5.83` шага, в худшем `10`. Дерево решений огромно для задачи (как я уже сказал—оптимальное решение не обязано только возможные варианты предлагать, то есть можно запросить xyzw, зная что это не ответ, чтобы например больше информации получить и за меньшее число шагов завершить)—существуют множество алгоритмов (в том числе AI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На качество прошу не смотреть, писалось со скоростью набора на коленке :)
В нескольких тестовых партиях угадывало за 5 вопросов. Эвристики никакой :), просто случайным образом берем первый попавшийся вариант из допустимых.

Модифицированные быки-коровы - с разрешенным повторением цифр; первая 0 быть не может.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> var;

class Checker
{
public:
    Checker(int val, int tot, int pos):val(val),tot(tot),pos(pos)
    {
        digs[0] = val/1000;
        digs[1] = val/100%10;
        digs[2] = val/10%10;
        digs[3] = val%10;
    };

    bool operator()(int chk) const
    {
        unsigned char cigs[4];
        cigs[0] = chk/1000;
        cigs[1] = (chk/100)%10;
        cigs[2] = (chk/10)%10;
        cigs[3] = chk%10;

        int position = (digs[0]==cigs[0]) + (digs[1]==cigs[1]) + (digs[2]==cigs[2]) + (digs[3]==cigs[3]);
        if (position != pos) return true;

        int tots = 0;
        bool is[4] = { false, false, false, false };
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            {
                if (is[j]) continue;;
                if (cigs[i] == digs[j])
                {
                    tots++;
                    is[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (tots != tot) return true;

        return false;
    }
private:
    int val, tot, pos;
    unsigned char digs[4];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i1 = 1; i1 < 10; ++i1)
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; ++i2)
            for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 10; ++i3)
                for(int i4 = 0; i4 < 10; ++i4)
                    var.push_back(((i1*10+i2)*10+i3)*10+i4);

    while(var.size() >= 1)
    {
        random_shuffle(var.begin(),var.end());
        cout << "Size = " << setw(4) << var.size() << "  > " << var[0] << "? ";
        int tot, pos;
        cin  >> tot >> pos;
        if (tot == 4 && pos == 4)
        {
            cout << "I won!\n";
            break;
        }
        var.erase(remove_if(var.begin(),var.end(),Checker(var[0],tot,pos)),var.end());
    }

}
```

**Update**. Провел эксперимент по отгадыванию всех 9000 чисел. Получилось *примерно* (прогнал только один цикл по всем числам) такие результаты:

```
  Попыток  Количество
  -------------------
        2          12
        3          91
        4         614
        5        1865
        6        3138
        7        2329
        8         763
        9         165
       10          23
```

Comment: Можете добавить пояснения к алгоритму? Не все люди на SO хорошо знают C. Я, например, рубист.

Comment: Я писал в комментариях к вопросу: составляю список всех возможных вариантов. Пока варианты есть - перетасовываю список случайным образом, и выдаю запрос из первого элемента. Получаю ответ, выбрасываю все элементы списка, которые не подходят под этот ответ. Повторяю цикл...